# Why Zero Lower bound makes fiscal consolidation more difficult?

Tags: macroeconomics

ZLB means the interest rate is near 0, and monetary policy does not work at that time, and someone who knows it?

Comment: What is fiscal consolidation?

Comment: Needs more detail/background.

Comment: @user253751 I assume they mean “ government policy intended to reduce deficits and the accumulation of debt”(https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php?title=Glossary:Fiscal_consolidation).